# Python: awaiting a list of coroutines sequentially

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-3.5, python-asyncio

I want to await a list of coroutines sequentially in Python, i.e. I do not want to use `asyncio.gather(*coros)`. The reason for this is that I'm trying to debug my app, so I want to pass a command-line switch to have things to run in a certain order, such that I get consistent behavior each time the app runs.

I tried doing it like this:

```
if args.sequential:
    fields = [await coro for coro in coros]
else:
    fields = await asyncio.gather(*coros)
```

But the sequential version doesn't seem to work correctly, i.e. I'm getting this warning:

```
sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'get_fields' was never awaited
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you think it's helpful do change essential behaviour like the execution order to debug a program?

Comment: You will not get sequential order if the async operations have already started, the only way is to start one and then wait for it before starting another. The two options you give should have the same effect except for the unexplained RuntimeWarning.

Comment: What is `coros` exactly?

Comment: @DanD. If `coros` is a list of coroutine objects that have not yet been submitted to an event loop, the above [would work](https://pastebin.com/nJs4kGGB). If it is a list of tasks, it will behave like you wrote.

Comment: @Vincent `coros = [async_op(x) for x in somelist]` where `async_op` is an `async def`.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help. I just noticed, only if the code in `async_op` threw an exception (because there were errors in my code, which is why I was debugging and not using `gather` in the first place) would this warning be issued. If there were no errors in my code, then the list comprehension would run sequentially without issue. So now the question is: why does this only happen if one of the `async_op` calls throws an exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once coroutine has been created somewhere, `asyncio` expects it would be awaited before event loop closed (before script finished execution):

```
import asyncio


async def bla():
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print('done')


async def main():
    bla()  # Create coro, but don't await


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Result:

```
RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'bla' was never awaited
```

We need this warning since it's very easy to forget about `await` while coroutine that was never awaited almost always means mistake.

Since one of your `async_op` threw an error, some coroutine created earlier was never awaited at the moment script finished. That's why you got warning.

In other words something like this has happened:

```
async def bla1():
    print('done')


async def bla2():
    raise Exception()


async def main():
    b1 = bla1()

    b2 = bla2()  # but here is exception ...

    await bla1()  # ... and this line was never reached
```